# Can't add (relatively) large amount of records with python to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have a word_set with ~170k elements and want to save it to MySQL database. My code works with small amount (for example 5 or 10 records) but returns an error with larger amount:

> 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system
> error: 10054 Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее
> подключение

Code:

```
from mysql.connector import connect, Error

try:
    with connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='root',
        port=3306,
        database='scrabble',
        # connection_timeout=20,
    ) as connection:
        insert_vocabulary = """
        INSERT INTO vocabulary
        (word)
        VALUES ( %s )
        """
        vocabulary_records = []
        for word in word_set:
            record = (word,)
            vocabulary_records.append(record)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.executemany(insert_vocabulary,
                               vocabulary_records)
            connection.commit()
except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

I tried specify connection_timeout=20 but it doesn't change anything. Error occurs within a second, definitely not 20 seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered increasing *max_allowed_packet* or running executemany() in batches. word_set is probably too large to do this in one invocation

Comment: 155k elements works, error occurs around 160k which is very close to full amount. So dividing into two batches easily solves the issue. Looks like a little bit inelegant solution thought, doesn't it?